# Kamailio not connects to remote database

Tags: kamailio

I have `Kamailio` on `ubuntu` at `10.10.145.189` and `mysql` on `centos` at `10.10.118.91`.

While installing `kamailio`, the command

/usr/local/sbin/kamdbctl create

worked and all databases created on `10.10.118.91` without any issue.
But when i try commands like

```
kamctl db show subscriber
```

it responds with error as follows.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kamailioro'@'ip-10-10-145-189.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)
```

10-10-145-189.ec2.internal was its hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating database users kamailio and kamailioro with host any.

Answer (score 0):

With the default configuration of `kamctctlrc`,  `/usr/local/sbin/kamdbctl create` will create the user `kamailio` in the mysql db with localhost and the IP of the mysql server as the `Host`. After that when you use the command `kamctl` it tries to access the mysql db with `kamailio@"IP_of_kamailio_server"` and hence the access is denied.

Try changing in the `kamctctlrc` file

- `DBACCESSHOST=IP_of_kamailio_server` to access the DB from the kamailio server
- or
- `DBACCESSHOST=%` to access the DB from any host for the user `kamilio`

and then create the schema in the DB `/usr/local/sbin/kamdbctl create`